# Combining Queries into one and iterate for multiple unique identifiers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to see if there is a way to combine CTE query and the Update query into one query. Also, I need to iterate the following query for multiple "AttributeId", when I try to put multiple AttributeID's in "in clause" it does not give me the result I want. Is there a better way of writing this query and instead of repeating the same query over and over again for different attribute ID - is the a way to write it like we write For Each loop? Thank you very much for your help!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can update a table from a CTE result.

I've already done that in the past and I've built [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a4d01/1/1) as an example if you want to see it live.

So, you need to use the UPDATE statement combined with the FROM clause and specify the "join" condition in the WHERE, like this:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    -- Fill the data you want to update
    SELECT personID, COUNT(1) AS count
        FROM person_movies
        GROUP BY personID
)
-- Update statement. You can use SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT or DELETE
UPDATE persons
    -- Specify the columns you want to update
    SET moviecount = CTE.count
    -- Specify the source, in this case is from the CTE
    FROM CTE
    -- How can we "link" the results in both tables? Specify it here
    WHERE persons.personID = CTE.personID
```